# TILT control a 3d obj file on libgdx

Tags: android, accelerometer, libgdx, tilt

I am a new to android development and libgdx...,

supposedly i loaded a 3d .obj file oval (earth) in libgdx and i wanted to control it using accelerometer downward and sideways..,

how could i do that any suggestion,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read accelerometer values for axises `x`, `y`, `z` use this

```
float accelX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
float accelY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
float accelZ = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ();
```

If you want to get rotation matrix for rendering from these values, its better to use `getRotationMatrix()` from [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) or its abstraction in [Input](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#getRotationMatrix%28float%5B%5D%29) class

```
public void getRotationMatrix (float[] matrix) {
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(matrix, null, accelerometerValues, magneticFieldValues);
}
```

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputAccelerometer)